# How to get Column values when user click on specific row in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, java-ee-6

iam developing an small Java EE application and i have created a servelt to enter student data to the database. i have displayed student data in another servlet using HTML table.in HTML table i have added a button to Update student data as the first column.that means in each row there is a update button.My problem is i want to get the corresponding second column value when user clicks on any row in order to update the student data.In second column i have student ID. Below is my code

Calling myFunction();

```
 out.println("<td><button type='button' onclick='myFunction()'>Update</button></td>");
```

MyJavascriptCode

```
 out.println("<script>");
 out.println("function myFunction()");
 out.println("{");
 out.println("var Row = document.getElementById('trid');");
 out.println("var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName('td');");
 //call update using EntityManager                
 out.println();
 out.println("}");
 out.println("</script>");
```

My second question is how can i access Row and Cells variables?
example: I want to print Row and Cells values using document.write();

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have some result list. For example, `List<Student>`.
In this case it will be:

```
    out.println("<td><button type='button'
       onclick='myFunction("+student.getId()+")'>Update</button></td>");
```

So you can pass student id into your javascript function.
But it would be better to display data using jstl and `<c:forEach>` tag.